# When is a group policy updated after a gpupdate is executed

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, group-policy

When a `gpupdate /force` is applied, is the group policy effected right then, or is it effected next logoff as when a update has occurred?

For example, lets say a you push a `gpupdate /force` onto an end users computer, is that Group Policy effected at that moment, or is it effected at next login?

According to the manual:

> Refreshes local and Active Directory-based Group Policy settings, including security settings. This command supersedes the now obsolete /refreshpolicy option for the secedit command.

But it does not specify when the update takes effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a group policy it will be applied after 90 minutes + 30 minute offset if the user is still logged in. Some policy's may require a reboot to take effect.

If the change is made and someone turns on their computer it will be applied on login.

When you do a `gpupdate /force` the policy will be updated instantly on that computer and will be applied at next login.

[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940895.aspx)

Comment: So all updates are applied either after 90 minutes, or after next login?

Comment: All group policy updates yes. usually with 30 minute offset so about 2 hours. Some policy's may require a reboot.

Comment: Awesome thanks man, I've been trying to research this all morning and found nothing on it.

Comment: @jakehimton no problem you could always check MSDN for questions regarding this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940895.aspx

Comment: I did, however it doesn't specify when the update takes place on the gpupdate page

Comment: My experience tells me, depending on which settings you changed, they are instant. In case it isn't, gpupdate /force will tell you: `The computer needs to reboot in order for some changes to be effective. Do you want to reboot now? [y,n]`

Comment: That's interesting.. Well here's the issue, every now and then (at my job) we get a kerbose protocol error due to a PIV system we use (card login). When we run a gpupdate and restart it usually fixes the issue. So my question is, do we really have to restart the system in order for this to take effect or can we just get them to login after we did a gpupdate

Comment: Usually the user rebooting the computer will fix it otherwise it will take 90 minutes +30 offset and a relogon in some cases. You could try a script that will run the gpupdate /force and then logs out the user when there is a changed policy. short intervals for policys are not usual.